# IE displaying nonstandard characters higher up than other text

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, special-characters

I can't figure this out. Can someone help? Rather than make a really complicated jsfiddle, I copy and pasted all of the necessary code to a bare bones html page.

http://brangeta.com/testing/problem.html

In IE9, the text on the far right is being displayed higher than the other text. I'm frustrated with the nonsensical developer tools in IE9 and can't figure out what can be tweaked. I tried adding "vertical-align: bottom;" and "line-height: 19pt;" to .topboilerplateheadings but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

In all other browsers the text is displaying just fine.

p.s. I am using a responsive bootstrap I've highly customized. There shouldn't be anything wrong with my html. There's just something not right in the CSS I am guessing. I am using jquery to make the hover effect on that pronunciation change to the actual word. It works in all browsers, but in IE9 it is making the word jump down from its elevated level which is about 5 to 10 px higher than the rest of the text which is wrong.

I want "/ˌenjәˈni(ә)r/" to be on the same baseline as the rest of the text, and ideally at the exact level the others are currently at. I thought it might be due to not using code for the special characters, but I don't know the &*_*; for these letters and can't find any search results for such.

Here's the code for when I remove that link from my site someday:

http://jsfiddle.net/nYAkR/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.row-fluid:before,
.row-fluid:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.row-fluid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.121475054229935%;
  *margin-left: 4.067245119305857%;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {
  margin-left: 4.121475054229935%;
}
.row-fluid .span3 {
  width: 16.702819956616054%;
  *width: 16.648590021691977%;
}
.row-fluid .offset1 {
  margin-left: 11.062906724511931%;
  *margin-left: 10.954446854663773%;
}
.row-fluid .offset1:first-child {
  margin-left: 6.941431670281996%;
  *margin-left: 6.83297180043384%;
}
h2 { /*main body headers and boilerplate headings*/
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Kozuka Gothic Pro", "Kozuka Gothic Pr6N", "Kozuka Gothic Std", Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:13pt;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:19pt;
    color:#58585A;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
a {
  color: #818285;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #58585a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topboilerplateheadings {
    color:#939598;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
</style>
  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-min.js" %3E%3C/script%3E'));
 }
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
  var prev;    

  $('.engineer').hover(function(){
  prev = $(this).text();
      $(this).text("engineer");
  }, function(){
      $(this).text(prev)
  });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span3">
<h2 class="topboilerplateheadings"><a href="#">&mdash; our story &mdash;</a></h2>
</div>

<div class="span3 offset1">
<h2 class="topboilerplateheadings"><a href="#">&mdash; news &mdash;</a></h2>
</div>

<div class="span3 offset1">
<h2 class="topboilerplateheadings"><a href="#">&mdash; events &mdash;</a></h2>
</div>

<div class="span3 offset1">
<h2 class="topboilerplateheadings"><a href="#">&mdash; <span class="engineer">/ˌenjәˈni(ә)r/</span> &mdash;</a></h2>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not provide vital information through a link only. The link will go away and your question is useless. Copy the relevant information into your question.

Comment: As an update, I have determined each of these four special characters is a problem causing this: ˌ ә ˈә. If I remove them, the alignment is fine. I need a fix that makes them work though.

Comment: I just figured out the solution via looking at the entire character set for the font I am using. http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans The reason the text was doing that is because the characters ˌ ˈ (whatever these are) don't exist in the font. If I replace with a comma and apostrophe the problem goes away. That's good enough for me. I was concerned I wouldn't be able to use ә, which would be a problem.